# ForeignKey displays a textbox instead of dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, kendo-grid

Here is my issue :

I have two project with similar code to display a dropdownlist inside a kendogrid. In the first project all works fine, in the second project i got a textbox dipslaying instead of a dropdown. I've searched around telerik but nothing could resolve my issue. I think something is missing in my project to make this work fine. Or something is blocking it ! But can't find .. Hope you could help me !

Here is my grid :

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<DisplayUniteMultiple>()
                              .Name("GridDisplayUniteMultiple")
                              .ToolBar(t => t.Create().Text("Ajouter un couple Valeur/ Unite"))
                              .Columns(columns =>
                              {
                                 columns.Bound(c => c.id).Hidden(true);
                                 columns.Bound(c => c.Valeur);
                                 columns.ForeignKey(c => c.Unite, unitesDeConversion, "Value", "Text").Title("Unité").Width(200);
                              })
                             .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).Enabled(true))
                             .Events(e => e.Edit("onGridChange"))
                             .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Update(builder => builder.Url(""))
                                .PageSize(50)
                                .Batch(false)
                                .Model(model =>
                                {
                                    model.Id(uniteMultiple => uniteMultiple.id);
                                    model.Field(uniteMultiple => uniteMultiple.Valeur);
                                    model.Field(uniteMultiple => uniteMultiple.Unite);
                                })
                                .ServerOperation(true)
                             ))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might missing to add the editor template in your project.

Create a new folder named `EditorTemplates` in `../Views/Shared/` directory, if there is not already. Then create new file named `GridForeignKey.cshtml` in that folder and copy below code into it, save and try again.

```
@model object

@(
  Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
     .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Comment: I'll try this, but it's strange because in the one where it work i don't have that folder and that file too.

Comment: i get the following error when i created the view : 
Error CS1061 'HtmlHelper<object>' does not contain a definition for 'Kendo' and no extension method 'Kendo' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper<object>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add `@using Kendo.Mvc.UI` in the first line

Comment: Still, i'd like to understand how it works in my other project since i didn't create the folder and the file

Comment: @ChristianPliso You can try compare files from both projects, if they are running on same version of kendo framework. I believe there should be an editor template already working for your other project.

Comment: Didn't think about making a Check before but i've shearched inside my project in visual and found the file in../View/Shared/EditorTemplates ! How could i miss this... mybad i have to open my eyes ! Anyway, thank you, know i'll not make the mistake again.